# Node.js async module value return

Tags: node.js, postgresql, asynchronous, tcp

I'm struggling to grasp how to use asynchronous programming. I have a tcp server that listens for connections, accepts packets, then passes the contained data to a module that generates keypairs and stores the whole mess in postgresql. I need to return the public key to the tcp server to pass back to the original packet sender. What I have now works but I believe it leaves the public key behind and passes undefined to the client. I can't decided if I'm just not understanding the process I'm using quite right or if I'm completely misunderstanding the whole process.

Here's my code

server:

```
    var net = require('net');
    var keys = require('./genKey.js');

    var HOST = '10.0.0.1';
    var PORT = 5555;

    net.createServer(function(sock) {

        console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);

        sock.on('data', function(data) {

            // console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);

            keys.genKey(data, out);

            //var public = console.log(String(keys.pub));
            **function out (pk) {
            console.log('out function called');
            var public = keys.pub;
            sock.write(public);**
            console.log(public);
            }

            //var promise = keys.genKey(data);
            //promise.then(console.log, console.error);

            //console.log(public);

            //sock.write(String(keys.pub));

        });
        sock.on('error', function (exc) {
        console.log("ignoring exception: " + exc);
    });

        sock.on('close', function(data) {
            console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
        });

    }).listen(PORT, HOST);

    console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

module:

```
    var Promise = require('promise');
    var cp = require('child_process')
      , assert = require('assert')
      ;
    const pool = require('./db');

    var prkey = '';
    var pukey = '';

    var privateKey, publicKey;
    publicKey = '';

    module.exports = {
    genKey: function(input) {
    cp.exec('openssl genrsa 2048', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
      assert.ok(!err);
      prkey = stdout;
      privateKey = stdout;
      //console.log(privateKey);
      //console.log('stdout: ', stdout);
      //prkey = privateKey;
      //console.log(prkey);
      makepub = cp.spawn('openssl', ['rsa', '-pubout']);
      makepub.on('exit', function(code) {
        assert.equal(code, 0);
        //console.log(publicKey);
        //pukey = publicKey;
        //console.log(pukey);
      });
      makepub.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        publicKey += data;
        pukey = String(publicKey);
        //console.log('stdout: ', publicKey);
        writeSQL(input, prkey, pukey);
        //console.log(pukey);
        //return {
        //pub: () => pukey
        // };
        **return pukey;**
      });
      makepub.stdout.setEncoding('ascii');
      makepub.stdin.write(privateKey);
      makepub.stdin.end();
    //console.log('stdout: ', stdout);
    });

    //console.log('output keys');
    //console.log(prkey);
    //console.log(pukey);
      //writeSQL(prkey, pukey);
    }
    };

    function writeSQL(uuid, private, public) {
      //console.log(private);
      //console.log(public);
      //console.log(uuid);
      console.log('write sql');
      //pool.query('INSERT INTO uuidkeys(uuid, public, private) values($1,$2, $3)',
      //  [uuid, public, private]);

    };
```

I apologize for the messy code, I've tried so many different things it has become very ugly.
If someone could tell me how to get my public key back to my server at the right point in my server function that would be great. Hopefully that will be sufficient to get me on the right track to understanding this.

Answer (score 0):

After a good deal of beating my head against the wall I finally grasp the way this works. None of the documents and tutorials I read (dozens of them) explained this in a way that clicked for me, I ended up trying everything I could think of and it finally worked.

The missing bit of info was an extremely basic explanation of what a callback is. I'll give my concept of it in case someone else stumbles across this struggling where i was.

The callback is another function you specify in your call to the function you want to use which is then called by the function you are using to return to the original process.

So from my code above:

Server

```
var keys = require('./genKey3.js');
var r = new keys();

call the function from the module
r.generate(data, /*pass this function to that function*/ function 
backed(key) 
{ 
        //do this when the backed function is called from the other function 
        console.log('out function called');
        console.log(key);
        sock.write(key);
        sock.on('close', function(data) {
             console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ 
        sock.remotePort);
        });
    });
```

module

```
this.generate = function(input, /*get your callback function here*/backed) {
    var privateKey, publicKey;
    publicKey = '';
    console.log('generate function called');
    cp.exec('openssl genrsa 2048', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        assert.ok(!err);
        privateKey = stdout;
        //console.log(privateKey);
        makepub = cp.spawn('openssl', ['rsa', '-pubout']);
        makepub.on('exit', function(code) {
            assert.equal(code, 0);
            //console.log(publicKey);
            writeSQL(input, privateKey, publicKey);

            //Get your info together and call the function passed from the 
            //starting point to return your data
            backed(publicKey);
        });
        //console.log('passed makepub.on');
        makepub.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            publicKey += data;
        });
        makepub.stdout.setEncoding('ascii');
        makepub.stdin.write(privateKey);
        makepub.stdin.end();
    });
};
```

It's actually cake when you get your head around it and I think if I had run across that explanation earlier it would taken me 15 minutes to get to that point.